# Use TCC1 timer to generate PWM on personnal board built with SAMD21E18A

Tags: pwm, timers, arduino-zero

I'm trying to generate a PWM signal from `TCC1`. I have a personnal board built with `SAMD21E18A`. I want to use pin 27 `PA30`, in my `variant.cpp` I have this line:

```c
{ PORTA, 30, PIO_PWM, PIN_ATTR_DIGITAL|PIO_SERCOM, No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, TCC1_CH0, EXTERNAL_INT_10 }, // SWCLK
```

I understand I can use `TCC1_CH0` on this pin with `PIO_TIMER`. Here is what I've tried at the end of my setup:

```c
  pinPeripheral(27, PIO_TIMER);
  pinMode(27, OUTPUT);

  ....

  Tcc* TC = (Tcc*)GetTC(TCC1_CH0);
  TC->CTRLA.reg &= ~TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE; 
  TC->CTRLA.reg |= TCC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV1; 
  TC->WAVE.reg |= TCC_WAVE_WAVEGEN_NPWM; 
  TC->PER.reg = 255; 
  TC->CC[0].reg = 128; 
  TC->CTRLA.reg |= TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE;
```

But it's not working: I have nothing on my pin.

Edit: I've also tried this in my setup:

```c
  GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID(TCC1_GCLK_ID) |
                     GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0 |
                     GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN;
  while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);

  Tcc* TC = (Tcc*) TCC1;
  TC->CTRLA.reg &= ~TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE; 

  TC->WAVE.reg = TCC_WAVE_WAVEGEN_NPWM;

  TC->CTRLA.reg |= TCC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV1 | 
                   TCC_CTRLA_RUNSTDBY;        

  PORT->Group[PORTA].PINCFG[30].bit.PMUXEN = 1; 
  PORT->Group[PORTA].PMUX[15].reg = PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_E; 

  TC->CC[0].reg = 1000;     
  TC->CC[1].reg = 4000;  

  // Activer le timer
  TC->CTRLA.reg |= TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE;
  while (TC->SYNCBUSY.bit.ENABLE);
```

I have something on my oscilloscope, but the signal seems not to be good, HIGH signal is very very quick and low signal very long.

Answer (score 1):

For example, settings for ATSAMR21G18A (it is similar to you MCU), PA08 PWM:

Pin init:

```
// GPIO PA08 PWM (DO)
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[8].reg = PORT_PINCFG_PMUXEN;
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[8/2].bit.PMUXE = PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_E_Val; // TCC0/WO[0]
```

Timer init:

```
void timer0_init()
{   
    GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg =   GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TCC0_TCC1 // Gen Clk Sel ID TCC0_TCC1
                | GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0    // Generic clock generator 0
                | GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN;       // Clock Enable
    
    PM->APBCSEL.reg = PM_APBCSEL_APBCDIV_DIV1;      // Divide by 1
    PM->APBCMASK.reg |= PM_APBCMASK_TCC0;           // TCC0 APB Clock Enable
    
    TCC0->WAVE.reg = TCC_WAVEB_WAVEGENB_NPWM;

    TCC0->PER.reg = 80; //TCC0/WO[0] PWM 100kHz DT=50%
    TCC0->CC->reg = 40;
    
    TCC0->CTRLA.reg = TCC_CTRLA_CPTEN0 | TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE;  // Enable                   
}
```

Comment: I have tried something similar @Dimitri but it's doesn't work my doubt come from this line in my `variant.cpp`{ PORTA, 30, PIO_PWM, PIN_ATTR_DIGITAL|PIO_SERCOM, No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, TCC1_CH0, EXTERNAL_INT_10 }, // SWCLK`I'm not sure about `NOT_ON_PWM` can I use `TCC1_CH0`for `PWM`??